# Build Select Options from two fields in AngularJS ng-options

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, I want what displays in the select to be a combination of two properties from the object in the array. For example, I have auctionName and auctionLocation on the item and I want the text in the display to appear like auctionLocation-auctionName.

```
<select  ng-model="selectedAuction" ng-options="item.auctionLocation as item.auctionLocation for item in auctions">
              <option value="" disabled selected>All Auctions</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values can be concatenated inside `ng-options`.

For your case you can use:

`ng-options="item.auctionLocation as item.auctionName+'-'+item.auctionLocation for item in auctions"`

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/uqoe0Hx4f0mOlU1f1wRE?p=preview